# Select all HTML elements with text

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I have HTML document:

```
<div class="blog">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="text"> Some text </p>
    <div class="date">23.12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i get all elements with inner text (.text, .date), but not wrapper (.content).

It's just an example, in real situation i don't know real HTML structure, but i need a method how select all elements with text, except their wrappers.

Need vanilla way help, without jquery.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 3):

```js
//first select the container
var container = document.body,
    //then all nodes
    elems = container.getElementsByTagName("*"),
    len = elems.length,
    elem,
    elemText,
    i,
    //we assign unnecessary elements
    unwanted = ["script", "images", "imput"];
//a normal loop
for(i=0;i<len;i+=1){
  elem = elems[i];
  //pay attention here
  //if the element does not have children it means that it will only contain text
  if(unwanted.indexOf(elem.nodeName.toLowerCase())=="-1"){
    if(!elem.children.length){
      //you also have to check that the text exists
      elemText = elem.innerText;
      if(elemText){
        //and finally
        console.log(elem, elemText);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blog">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="text"> Some text </p>
    <div class="date">23.12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @VladimirHumeniuk you're welcome, I've added something else. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get container, then all children, then filter those children. If this is going into a production environment, you'll want to do some error checking and make sure none of those elements return null, undefined or some other bad value.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.content'),
    allKids = container.querySelectorAll('*'),
    kidsWithContent = Array.from(allKids).filter(item => item.textContent.length !== 0);
    
console.log(kidsWithContent);
```

```html
<div class="blog">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p class="text"> Some text </p>
    <div class="date">23.12</div>
    <p></p>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is - i don't know parent element HTML structure, so i can't select wrapper element ('.content').

Comment: ok, then for `container` use the highest element you are aware of. But that may make the query slower in large documents.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way (assuming the elements contain classes `text` and `date`)

```js
var coll = document.querySelectorAll(".text, .date"); //Get HTML elements having class .text and .date
var elements = [].slice.call(coll); //Convert to array
elements.map(function(el,i) { console.log(el.innerHTML.trim()) });   //Display element innerHTML using `map` function
```

```html
<div class="blog">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <p class="text"> Some text </p>
        <div class="date">23.12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```